# REST API from ADF : Checking if https URL is available or not

Tags: azure-data-factory, rest

Assume the target is REST API via https which has usual firewall etc and data is in json format.

Even before downloading the data from this, I want to check whether I can access the https URL.
If there is any issue then ADF should be able to Auto-Retry 5 times with a 10 seconds interval between 2 tries.

If ADF can't reach the URL after 3 attempts then it should be able to send mail automatically to an email id with a predefined message about the issue.

How to achieve this functionality in ADF?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is to retry URL 5 times with retry interval of 10 seconds.

To achieve this, Select Web activity in Adf pipeline.

As shown in below screenshot you can give Retry as 5 and retry interval of 10 seconds.

[image]

Second part of your question is to send email notification if error occurred.

To achieve this, there is no *Send Email Activity* in Azure Data Factory. However, you can send email notification of error message using *Logic app*.

I have shared 2 links of articles by Koen Verbeeck, In first link you will find how to create Logic app with relevant Logic and in second link you will find how to use Logic app in adf.

1. [Link1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5718/azure-data-factory-pipeline-email-notification-part-1/)
2. [Link2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5962/send-notifications-from-an-azure-data-factory-pipeline-part-2/)

Comment: Or instead of use logic apps they can create a new service where they can send error code with message to send the notification. That new service they can implement it on ADF.